# Android YouTube integration, Remove YouTube logo

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have integrated YouTube player to my app.
The problem now is, YouTube logo is displayed in the player and when i click on it, it takes to YouTube app.

Is it possible to remove YouTube logo from player? If not , is it possible to remove click event on the YouTube logo?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Usually, google services only work if you show the according logo

Comment: Try changing the play style, maybe the logo ist not overlayed in all styles:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle

Comment: They show their logo in return for you burning their bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others, it is **mandatory** for you to display YouTube logo in your application in case you do not want to violate [YouTube Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Look Under API USE:

> 4. **Brand Feature Rules.** "YouTube Brand Features" means the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names and other
>      distinctive brand features of YouTube. YouTube grants You a
>      non-exclusive license to use the YouTube Brand Features solely in
>      connection with their display on or through the API Client as
>      delivered by YouTube. Your Application shall provide proper
>      attribution to YouTube as specified in the YouTube Brand Guidelines
>      set forth at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/branding.html, which
>      may be modified by YouTube at any time. YouTube may terminate Your
>      license to use the YouTube Brand Features at any time for any or no
>      reason. Goodwill in YouTube Brand Features will inure only to
>      YouTube's benefit and You obtain no rights with respect to any of
>      them. You irrevocably assign and will assign to YouTube any right,
>      title and interest that You obtain in any of YouTube's Brand Features.
>      You shall not at any time challenge or assist others to challenge
>      YouTube Brand Features or their registration (except to the extent You
>      cannot give up that right by law) or attempt to register any
>      trademarks, marks or trade names confusingly similar to YouTube's.
>      This paragraph survives any termination or expiration of this
>      Agreement.

As far as removing the link goes, even that is against YouTube's branding policy. Look at the last point at the bottom of the page in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/branding_guidelines?csw=1):

> Any YouTube logo used within an application must link back to YouTube
>   content or to a YouTube component of that application.

Hence, I would really suggest leaving that logo and link there. However, meeting the requirements, you could re-size it a little in case if it is big or small.