# How to implement only ON and OFF option on youtube video player?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have  a youtube video in my website. Here is the code :

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtube_key; ?>?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&modestbrandin=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

I want that user can only see the video. I mean user can play it or pause it. No other control even I DON'T WANT user can right click on the video player.

Now this code invisible all option but user can right click and can copy the url :(

How can I implement this type of youtube in my website where user can only see it only from my website. any suggestion ?

Comment: The simple answer to your question is, you can't. Not without violating [Youtube API ToS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms), at least. Take a look at this answer I provided. Although your use case is different the answer is pretty much similar. Youtube lets you access their data through their API for free, in return they need you to adhere to certain policies regarding the branding of YouTube data that is shown on your website/device. Trying to mess with the links or the logo that leads the user back to YouTube, is against their policy. Hence, I'd suggest leave it as is.

Comment: *[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996889/android-youtube-integration-remove-youtube-logo/34097066#34097066)